# Getting Data provider exception in appium

Tags: selenium, testng, appium, testng-dataprovider

Getting Data provider exception in Appium, exception loag added below:

> org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException:  Data provider
>   mismatch

What I have tried, the code putted below:

```
@DataProvider(name = "getDataFromExcel")
    public static Object[][] GetData() throws IOException, BiffException{

        File f = new File("/Users/aakibqureshi/Downloads/BrowsersUrl.xls");
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);

        int rows = sheet.getRows();
        int cols = sheet.getRow(0).length;

        String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];

        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            data[i][1] = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(1,i).getContents();
            //System.out.println(data[i][1]);

        }
        return data;
    }

   @Test(dataProvider = "getDataFromExcel")
    public static void SimpleTest(String url) throws IOException {

       driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.findElementById("org.chromium.chrome:id/terms_accept").click();
       driver.findElementById("org.chromium.chrome:id/next_button").click();
       driver.findElementById("org.chromium.chrome:id/negative_button").click();
       driver.findElementById("org.chromium.chrome:id/search_box_text").click();


       driver.findElementById("org.chromium.chrome:id/url_bar").click();
       System.out.println(url);

   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data provider mismatch in Selenium with TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998857/data-provider-mismatch-in-selenium-with-testng)

Comment: Include full stackTrace information, which might helpful to go through.