# Data provider mismatch

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've received an error after running a test script. I already run the same method in other test scripts but this script I've been using is almost the same of the other test scripts. Can you help me why this error occurs?

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: validatingErrorMessages
```

This is the method of getting excel data.

```
public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName)
        throws BiffException, IOException {
    String[][] arrayExcelData = null;

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

    int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
    int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

    arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows - 1][totalNoOfCols];

    for (int i = 1; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
            arrayExcelData[i - 1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
        }

    }
    return arrayExcelData;
}
```

Here is my Data Provider method

```
@DataProvider(name = "login")
public Object[][] loginData() throws BiffException, IOException {
    Object[][] arrayObject = testDataXls.getExcelData(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\InputData.xls",
            this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return arrayObject;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data provider mismatch in Selenium with TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998857/data-provider-mismatch-in-selenium-with-testng)

Comment: I tried to put all my values into String and it doesn't work

Comment: Show your data provider method

Comment: Below is my data provider method

Comment: And also please show the signature of your test method.

Comment: Also why your data provider method is not annotated with `@DataProvider`?

Comment: Hi Alexey, I posted my data provider above.